# Tensorflow efficient pairwise inner product

Tags: python, tensorflow, inner-product

In Tensorflow (python), given a matrix *X* of shape *(n x d)*, where each row is a data point, I would like to compute the pairwise inner products of these *n* data points, *i.e.*, the upper triangle of *XX'*.

Of course I could compute the whole *XX'* and fetch its upper triangle, but this means I would compute the off-diagonal elements **twice**. How to compute these efficiently in Tensorflow (python) by computing the inner product only once per pair?

Comment: @greeness Sorry but I don't quite understand. X may be not square. Could you show me some code?

Comment: I think I was wrong. I deleted my previous comment. In python, I have no idea how this can be done. I would like to see an answer too. I did not look  at the kernel source code, but I suspect that since `tf.matmul` accepts an input argument `transpose_b` it might has internal optimization already from the BLAS library. I mean it is highly probable  that the saving of computation is already being considered.

Answer (score 0):

With numpy, you can do this:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randn(5, 3)
inds = np.triu_indices(5) # upper triangle indices

# expensive way to do it
ipu1 = np.dot(A, A.T)[inds]


# possibly less expensive way to do it.
ipu2 = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', A[inds[0]], A[inds[1]])

print(np.allclose(ipu1, ipu2))
```

This outputs True. Tensorflow does not have the triu_indices function build in, but it is not hard to write one if needed by looking at the numpy code. It does have einsum.

Comment: OP had requested for a solution in TF and not numpy. Implementing triu_indices defeats the purpose of avoiding the dual computation performed on the off-diagonal elements since we would need to compute the entire XX' first.